# How do I separate output from database?

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried to get multiple rows out from my database with PHP but all I get is one line of text like: "8910"

My code is following:

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE idUsers=$id";
  $sth = $conn->query($sql);
  if(!$sth) {
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    die();
  }

  $rows = mysqli_num_rows($sth);

  for ($x = 0; $x <= $rows; $x++) {
       $sql = "SELECT idPosts FROM posts WHERE idUsers=$id";
       if(!$sth) {
         echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
         die();
       }
       $result = mysqli_fetch_array($sth);

       $postId = $result['idPosts'];

       echo $postId;

  }
```

And then I edit this: echo `$postId." ";`

And get a space between the id's like this: 8 9 10.

I tried to do `$postIds = explode(" ", $postId);`

And then echoing out for example `$postIds[0]` but I get all the id's once again

Now I do not know what to do so I need help ^^

Comment: You realize that your second request can be made without the first one ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$postId = $result['idPosts'];` with `$postId[] = $result['idPosts'];`. That way you create an array an you can just access it like `$postId[0]`.

You also forgot to query again.

```
...
$sql = "SELECT idPosts FROM posts WHERE idUsers=$id";
$sth = $conn->query($sql);
if(!$sth) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second query is unnecessary, you already have all the data from your first query. Just replace your code with this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE idUsers=$id";
$sth = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$sth) {
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    die();
}
$postIds = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sth)) {
    $postIds[] = $result['idPosts'];
}
```

After this loop you will have an array of all the `idPosts` values. You can then process them as you need to. Or you can process them in the loop:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sth)) {
    $postId = $result['idPosts'];
    // code to process postId e.g.
    echo "$postId<br/>";
}
```

Comment: wait... I'm a bit confused over what you are saying atm... Could you explain just a bit more ^^

Comment: @Kevlar2228 see my edit, the first example now includes all the code required. For the second one you would just replace the `while` loop in the first example.

Comment: Ok yeah I got that covered. But then how do I break them out in to separate callable arrays? I want to be able to call the posts with the specific postId to display on my site

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You should probably add a new question and explain what the expected output is.